# How to update/redraw QChart after data is added to QLineSeries?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, updates, qchart

I am generating some data that I want to chart using **QChart** & friends. This is my first time using `QChart`, and so basically what I did was copy the [QLineSeries Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-linechart-example.html) and modify it to my needs. My current code looks like this:

```
    quint64 last=0;
    quint64 *lastp=&last;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , series( nullptr )
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    series=new QLineSeries(chart);
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");
    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    setCentralWidget(chartView);
    GeneticTask *gTask = new GeneticTask();
    connect(gTask, &GeneticTask::point, this, [=](QPointF pt) {
        // New point added to series
        *series<<pt;
        // Limit updates to once per second
        quint64 now=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
        if(now-(*lastp)>1000) {
            qDebug()<<"UPDATE";
            // [A] WHAT TO PUT HERE TO HAVE CHART REDRAW WITH NEW DATA?
            *lastp=now;
        }
    }
    );
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(gTask);
}
```

When I run this code I would expect my new data to show up in the graph, but it does not, so my question is: *How can I have the chart update to show the new data?* In other words, what should I put in the code where the comment reads `[A]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appending a value to `QLineSeries` using the operator `<<` or the `append` method should repaint the graph. If it does not happen form some reason, you could trying calling the `repaint` method on the `QChartView`.

Here is some code that will center the data once it is added with a cap of at most once per second:

```
// Global or class scope or
qreal max=-10000000000;
qreal min=-max;
qreal *maxp=&max;
qreal *minp=&min;

// Same scope as before
connect(gTask, &GeneticTask::point, this, [=](QPointF pt) {
        if(pt.y()>*maxp) {
            *maxp=pt.y();
        }
        if(pt.y()<*minp) {
            *minp=pt.y();
        }
        *series<<pt;
        quint64 now=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
        if(now-(*lastp)>1000) {
            qDebug()<<"UPDATE";
            chart->axisX()->setRange(0,series->count());
            chart->axisY()->setRange(*minp,*maxp);

            *lastp=now;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: As a note, the data was being added and updated, but I had to manually center on the new data. I have taken the liberty of adding the details to your answer.

Comment: You can also use chart->createDefaultAxes();

Answer (score 1):

Little correction to the answer above. Qt Documentation says:

> `void QWidget::repaint()`
> Repaints the widget directly by calling
> paintEvent() immediately, unless updates are disabled or the widget is
> hidden. We suggest only using repaint() if you need an immediate
> repaint, for example during animation. In almost all circumstances
> update() is better, as it permits Qt to optimize for speed and
> minimize flicker.
> Warning: If you call repaint() in a function which
> may itself be called from paintEvent(), you may get infinite
> recursion. The update() function never causes recursion.

As result, `QChartView::update()` works for me.