# Updating QLineSeries in Chart doesnt work at all

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm melting my brain right now and cant figure out, why my chart isn't updating at all.
I've declared the following in my applications  `*.h`-File:

```
QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QChart* chart;
QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QLineSeries* series;
QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QChartView* chartView;
```

In my constructor of my mainwindow `*.cpp` file I've written

```
this->series= new QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QLineSeries();
this->chart = new QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QChart();
this->chartView = new QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QChartView(chart);
this->chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
.
. 
.
this->series->clear();
this->chart->legend()->hide();

this->setPlotAreaBackgroundVisible(true);

this->series->setVisible(true);
this->chart->addSeries(this->series);
this->chart->createDefaultAxes();
```

Right now `series` is empty, and i know from the Qt Docs that my graph should be updated every time the `append()` emits it's signal.

After all this instantiation my application does its jobs. In a slot from another thread some data should be appended to the series:

```
 /*Some other things*/
 
 this->seriesXIncrement++;
 QPoint point = QPoint(this->seriesXIncrement,this->parsedReadCommand.toUInt());
 this->series->append(point);
 qDebug()<<this->series->points().size();

 this->chart->createDefaultAxes();
 this->chartView->repaint();
```

I've validated the append method with `qDebug`. It's size is growing as expected, also the points I'm creating are valid, but on my graph nothing happens. I'm not sure if `createDefaultAxes()`  is the way to go for updating the axes as well, but i thought this is a relatively easy and lazy approach.

Comment: `In a slot from another thread some` - what does this mean? You must not modify the gui from another thread than the main gui thread.

Comment: Ah, sorry if this was a bit confusing. To clear this up:
The Thread reads from a serial device and in the slot (partly shown above)  the gui reacts to the emitted signal from the thread. There is no problem at all, the threads are working like a charm. 
But, in the slot the data is also appended to the ```series``` to be shown in the graph.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010572/how-to-update-redraw-qchart-after-data-is-added-to-qlineseries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that `createDefaultAxes()` caused this problem. I inserted both (x,y) axis insted of `createDefaultAxes()` like so:

```
 QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QValueAxis *axisX = new QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QValueAxis;
  axisX->setRange(0, this->series->points().length());
  axisX->setTickCount(10);
  axisX->setLabelFormat("%d");
  chartView->chart()->setAxisX(axisX, series);

  QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QValueAxis *axisY = new QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE::QValueAxis;
  axisY->setRange(0, 50);
  axisY->setTickCount(1);
  axisY->setLabelFormat("%d");
  chartView->chart()->setAxisY(axisY, series);
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: `easy_chart.cpp:29:12: warning: 'setAxisX' is deprecated
qchart.h:107:5: note: 'setAxisX' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
qcompilerdetection.h:227:45: note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECL_DEPRECATED'`